# Intercept request for a static file in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node server, that serves static files in a PUBLIC folder like this:

```
var app = express();
app.listen(port);
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/PUBLIC'));
```

There is a json file, let's say important.json that is located in /PUBLIC folder. This is being served as a static file

Now, I want to intercept request for this /PUBLIC/important.json, so that I can programatically return a random json structure instead.

None of the followings works:

```
app.get('/PUBLIC/important.json', function(req, res) {
    console.log("caught1!")
});

app.get(__dirname + '/PUBLIC/important.json', function(req, res) {
    console.log("caught2!")
});

app.get('important.json', function(req, res) {
    console.log("caught3!")
});
```

How can I intercept request for that partically static file?

Comment: Is important.json something you would like to hide from the public? Because if it is, you must not put it in the public folder. No matter how hard you try, there will always be a way to bypass your middleware, and the file will be served ultimately. (First thing comes to my mind is unicode strings which normalize to "important.json")

Comment: No it is not a secret file. It used to be a static json that hardly changes, but due to change of requirements, we want the json data to be partially dynamic, so I m trying to intercept that and do something about that request programatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the `express.static` middleware does not call the next middleware using `next()`, the definition order is important. You have to define your own middleware *before* using `express.static`.

```
app.get('/PUBLIC/important.json', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('caught');
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/PUBLIC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell us a bit more about your stack ?

Are you using nginx / apache to proxy_pass the traffic to your nodejs server ?

Are you just running your app with "node app.js"

Let's try to add this simple route in your application :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

And try to access it by removing URI parameters ? Does the "Hello world" show up ?

I just want to be sure the traffic is actually treated by your node app.

Your route definition is supposed to work for your actual request.

Comment: no. hello world will not show up, the index page in the PUBLIC folder will show up as usual.